# bootstrap toggle - value change and array generation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, toggle

I'm trying to use bootstrap-toggle plugin in one of my personal project. It's all nice and pretty and work as advertised, except that it doesn't.

What I mean by that is that the animation works fine but the underlying input does not change/toggle the state change.

So here's my code:

```
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" class="filter-toggle" value="1">mango
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" class="filter-toggle" value="2">strawberries
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" class="filter-toggle" value="3">tangerine
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" class="filter-toggle" value="4">peach
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" class="filter-toggle" value="5">pineapple
        </label>
        </div>
```

what I need to do is on click toggle the underlying checkbox "checked" attribute, and then get all checked checkboxes and put them into array for ajax actioning. I would imagine it to be as simple as:

```
var arr = [];    
$('element').on('click',function(){
        $('.filter-toggle input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
         arr.push($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

obviously it's not or I wouldn't be here and the official documentation and examples are not helpfull at all.

So in brief, using bootstrap-toggle plugin, how do I check/uncheck the underlying checkboxes and get values into js array?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
var arr = [];
$("#btnFind").on("click", function() {
  $(".filter-toggle").each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {      
      arr.push($(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
</head>


<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" class="filter-toggle" value="1">mango
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" class="filter-toggle" value="2">strawberries
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" class="filter-toggle" value="3">tangerine
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" class="filter-toggle" value="4">peach
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" class="filter-toggle" value="5">pineapple
  </label>
</div>
<input id="btnFind" type="button" value="Find Selected" class="btn btn-success" />

</html>
```

Comment: that works, but I guess I forgot to specify I need it to happen on the fly, after each button is toggled, without the need to us extra button

Comment: this is also possible but I think If you are pushing it to an array on client side you can do it at once when it is required for better performance.